# Embed Python in C++ (using CMake)

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I'm trying to run a python script in c++. For example:

```
// main.cpp
#include <python3.10/Python.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is',ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And I have such CMakeLists:

```
// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(task_01)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package (Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.10 REQUIRED)
include_directories ( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(task_01 main.cpp)
```

But I get compile errors (I use CLion IDE):

```
undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
```

What am I doing wrong to run a python script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefer imported targets (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#imported-targets):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(task_01)

find_package(Python REQUIRED Development)

add_executable(task_01 main.cpp Utility.cpp Sort.cpp)
target_link_libraries(task_01 PRIVATE Python::Python)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Individually targeting lib files and lib & includes directories is brittle and hard to maintain.  Modern packages that have CMake configurations exposed will have packages you can target which will automatically trigger the appropriate directory inclusions, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Such configurations in CMakeLists.txt helped me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(task_01)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package (Python REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

add_executable(task_01 main.cpp Utility.h Utility.cpp Sort.h Sort.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${Python_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${Python_LIBRARIES})
```